# Unity code cleaning: writing general shooting script implementing same methods from different bullet classes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, data-cleaning

I picked up unity and C# a month ago so I'm still a noobie.

So far I managed to build a simple space-based arcade shooter (i have my ship, i have a way to shoot bullets). What I'm trying to achieve is a way to keep the script that takes my keyboard input to shoot separate from the possible bullet types.
The way my bullet types are currently implemented is by having a gameobject for each with its own scripts for a) taking keyboard input and b) instancing a prefab with different properties to shoot. Currently i have 2 shooting modes, and a separate script lets me swap between them with the spacebar by enabling disabling the gameobjects. An example of the scripts I'm using for one bullet type:

Script for instantiating bullet. One method simply shoots every time a button is pressed, the other "charges" an array of bullets, accompanied in the second script by a "growing aura" signifing the power increase. These two methods have the same name across different bullet classes, but are implemented differently.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletA_Basic : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public GameObject aura;
    public Transform firingPoint;
    public Transform chargingPoint;

    public float bulletForce = 20f;
    public float altCooldown = 1f;
    public float fireRate = 1f;
    public float altFirePowerMultiplier = 1f;

    private void Update()
    {
    }

    public void Shoot()
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firingPoint);
        Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.AddForce(firingPoint.up * bulletForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
    
    public void SpecialShoot(int n)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Special(n));
    }
    public IEnumerator Special(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Shoot();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

        }
    }
}
```

Script for taking keyboard input

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting_A : MonoBehaviour //This needs to be copied across all firing types
{
    private BulletA_Basic bulletScript; //Change the class to make new projectile types with different firing modes
    public Vector3 scaleChange;
    private GameObject auraInstance;
    private float timePassed = 0f;
    private float timePassedMain = 0f;
    public float timeToDetonation = 3f;


    private void Start()
    {
        bulletScript = GetComponent<BulletA_Basic>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        bool isFiring = Input.GetButtonDown("Main Cannon");
        bool alternateFire = Input.GetButton("Main Cannon");
        

        
        timePassedMain += Time.deltaTime;

        if (isFiring && timePassedMain > bulletScript.fireRate) 
        {
            bulletScript.Shoot();   
            timePassedMain = 0;
        }
        

        if (alternateFire)
        {
            timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

            if (!auraInstance && timePassed >= bulletScript.altCooldown)
            {
                auraInstance = Instantiate(bulletScript.aura, bulletScript.chargingPoint);
            }

            if (alternateFire && auraInstance && timePassed < timeToDetonation)
            {
                Charge();
                //Will need to add shader here
            }

            else if (timePassed >= timeToDetonation)
            {
                Destroy(auraInstance);
                timePassed = 0;  
            }
        }

        else
        {
            if (auraInstance) 
            {
                Destroy(auraInstance);
                int powerAltFire = (int)(bulletScript.altFirePowerMultiplier * (Mathf.Pow(2 , timePassed)));         //Equation returns a number of projectiles based on how long charge was held   
                bulletScript.SpecialShoot(powerAltFire);
            }

            timePassed = 0;      
        }      
    }

   

    void Charge()
    {
        auraInstance.transform.localScale += scaleChange;
    }

}
```

The key here is the bulletScript field.

Basically i'd like to make the second script general so that i don't have to implement it in a different way and copy-pasting it again and again for each type of bullet I'm going to make, and changing the bulletScript field type each time.

I tried doing it with interfaces but I'm not sure how to implement it in the general script since I need to access each field of the subclasses, which have each their own references (like bulletPrefab, or aura). In general i feel interfaces are not well integrated into unity but that might just be me.

I also tried with delegates, but i had similar problems. I simply changed the type of bulletScript to my delegate type (ShootingDelegate bulletScript), and wrote this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public delegate void ShootDelegate();
public delegate void SpecialShootDelegate(int n);


public class ShootingDelegate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ShootDelegate delShoot;
    public SpecialShootDelegate delSpecialShoot;
    private int weaponIndex;

    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public GameObject aura;
    public Transform firingPoint;
    public Transform chargingPoint;

    public float bulletForce;
    public float altCooldown;
    public float fireRate;
    public float altFirePowerMultiplier;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        WeaponSwap weapon = GetComponent<WeaponSwap>();
        weaponIndex = weapon.weaponIndex;
        
        switch (weaponIndex)
        {
            case 1:
                BulletB_Fan bulletB = GetComponent<BulletB_Fan>();

                delShoot = bulletB.Shoot;
                delSpecialShoot = bulletB.SpecialShoot;

                bulletPrefab = bulletB.bulletPrefab;
                aura = bulletB.aura;
                firingPoint = bulletB.firingPoint;
                chargingPoint = bulletB.chargingPoint;
                bulletForce = bulletB.bulletForce;
                altCooldown = bulletB.altCooldown;
                fireRate = bulletB.fireRate;
                altFirePowerMultiplier = bulletB.altFirePowerMultiplier;
                break;

            case 0:
                BulletA_Basic bullet = GetComponent<BulletA_Basic>();

                delShoot = bullet.Shoot;
                delSpecialShoot = bullet.SpecialShoot;

                bulletPrefab = bullet.bulletPrefab;
                aura = bullet.aura;
                firingPoint = bullet.firingPoint;
                chargingPoint = bullet.chargingPoint;
                bulletForce = bullet.bulletForce;
                altCooldown = bullet.altCooldown;
                fireRate = bullet.fireRate;
                altFirePowerMultiplier = bullet.altFirePowerMultiplier;
                break;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

This is the error it throws:

> ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
> ShootingDelegate.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/ShootingDelegate.cs:54)

which corresponds to this line

delShoot = bullet.Shoot;

I don't really care if a solution employs either interfaces or delegates, those were just things I tried. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample just for you.
Here I am creating **BulletType** parent class for all bullet types. And atting some variable and method for all bullets.

```
public class BulletType : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Protected is less stric than private, more stric than public
    // Protected variables only accesible to this class and its child.
    protected string name;
    protected int bulletDamage;
    protected int bulletSpeed;

    protected virtual void Start()
    {

    }

    // Virtual means you can override this method in child classes
    protected virtual void Damage() { }

    public virtual void PlaySound() { }

    protected virtual void ShowEffect() { }
}
```

Now I will add child class and inherit from parent **BulletType** class. Everything write in comment lines.

```
// This class inherits from BulletType class.
public class FireBullet : BulletType
{
    // If you want to completely ignore parent class variable to by adding new keyword.
    new int bulletSpeed = 3;

    protected override void Start()
    {
        // when overriding a method automatically adds this method.
        // base means parent class. with base you can access parent methods.
        base.Start();

        // If you remove base method, parent method won't be called in this class.

        // Here I accessed parent class variable and set its value.
        // This doesn't effect parent or other child classes. That's the beauty.
        name = "Fire Bullet";
    }

    void StopSound() 
    { 
    }

    protected override void PlaySound()
    {
        // Sound played from parent.
        base.PlaySound();

        // You can add your own variable and methods in parent method.
        StopSound();
    }
}

// FireBullet inherited from BulletType, and LavaBullet inherited from FireBullet.
// You can do this as much as you want.
public class LavaBullet : FireBullet
{
    protected override void PlaySound()
    {
        // Here base will be FireBullet
        base.PlaySound();
    }
}

public class IceBullet : BulletType
{
    // Add as much as you thing.
}
```

And for using **BulletType** script in your player just add this line

```
public class Player
{
    public BulletType currentBulletType;
    // You can get child from main class. 
    FireBullet fireBullet = currentBulletType.GetComponent<FireBullet>();
    // Now you can access and use child class methods.
    fireBullet.PlaySound();
}
```

and when you want to change bullet type, just assign new bullettype. Because all bullet type inherit from this class. You can assign every bullet type.

Comment: I made the BulletType class and made the bullet child classes all inherit from it, but I can't access the methods from my Player class because they are set to protected. Also, it is not clear to me how i would go about changing the variable in player to be able to reference the child classes. Calling currentBulletType.Damage() is not possible because they are protected, and if I make them public it's just calling empty methods not the ones of the subclasses. I'd have to instantiate the subclass and call for example fireBullet.Damage() which would make the whole parent class thing moot.

Comment: You can access childs. All child have reference to parent. As an example if you have currently Fire Bullet, you can say *BulletType bullet;* and **bullet.GetComponent<FireBullet>();** With that way you can access child class and use its methods. Also, I updated last part of my question.

Comment: The other issue is that the different bullet scripts are attached to game objects, because this way i can easily assign the fields to my prefabs by drag and drop. But if I try writing currentBulletType = new FireBullet for example it throw Argument Exception: the object you want to instantiate is null (obviously, because I didn't assign the fields to the new instance). I'd need a way to reference the script inside that game object so that it gets the same properties.

Comment: Why did you code as **new FireBullet**. **FireBullet** class has no constructor. You should assign BulletType to a prefab and and assign (Fire Bullet). Then in code **GetComponent<FireBullet>()**

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. After adding the scripts to a gameobject I cannot assign either BulletType or FireBullet fields (like bulletSpeed) because they are protected. For the exact same reason I can't write in another script not inheriting from BulletType `FireBullet fireBullet = currentBulletType.GetComponent<FireBullet>()`, since that throw an error like **BulletType.bulletSpeed is not accessible due to protection level**

Comment: I already explained this in my answer post. Protected is stricter than public. You can't acces it from another class. Just changed it to public, or for better leave it and create public property that return and set for every protected field. That way your code will have better protection and less error.

Comment: Also I suggest you to read about [C# Access Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers). Also, [C# Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). If you have clear understanding in this topic, your code will be more readable and have less future problems. Just note it is a bad practise to make every field public, public accessor make your code accessible to everywhere. Every class and assembly.

Comment: In Unity if you're creating a MonoBehavior, and you want to expose a value to the editor, then fields are your only option. Properties don't show up in the editor.

Comment: No. You can use [SerializeField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) Attribute. This attribute will expose valuse to the Unity editor even if they have private accessors. Also in custom editor you can expose property value to the editor.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's the answer but,

> delShoot = bulletB.Shoot;

**delShoot** is a reference to a script.

**bulletB.Shoot** is a function.

I don't think you can make one equal to the other.

If I understand your question, you want to make one script for two type of bullets shoot. You can create a scipts Shoot.cs who is instantiate with a value (1 for the default fire 2 for the second fire) and other scrits defaultFire.cs / secondFire.cs with they own properties.

Like this you'll juste instantiate once your **Bullet** like this :

```
public void Start(){
  case 1 : Shoot shoot = new Shoot(1)
  case 2 : Shoot shoot = new Shoot(2)
}
```

Hope this help a little..

Comment: You mean making all bullet types in a single script, and using method overloads? That's fine but gets really messy if I start adding more and more bullet types, especially because I need to define public properties for each one of them. What if I want different scripts for different bullet types, and want to access them from a single general shooting script that takes keyboard input and shoot the bullet that is selected?

Comment: @Leureka what you want is [Polymorphism](https://docs.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism). But it is intermediate level. Anyway I will try to explain as simple as possible: You can create BulletType class and you add the **property and methods** that every bullet class have to has. Like every bullet will have: (damage, speed, Damage method, destroy method, name etc.). Then you add child class and childeren classes will inherit from parent **BulletType** class. With this way every child going to have all parent class properties and methods.

Comment: If parent field/properties/methods are not marked as private, childeren classes will be able to see and use them. Also if you want a method to have in all child class except one of them, you can override this method in this child class and modify it or completly ignore it. Polymorphism is a really good programming methodology. If you want your code more readable and easily editable, I suggest it. If you want any sample I can post them to.

Comment: @SeLeCtRa that sounds a lot like what I need. How do I reference a particular method in one of the child classes? Would doing something like the following work: make parent class like you said, implement child classes with different methods for each bullet; in main script, enable a single game object with the bullet type i want and disable the rest, then call the method of the parent class